# Does Hinduism have any test for virginity?

Tags: scripture, practice, women, men, virginity

Do Hindu scriptures tell us how to test if someone is a virgin or not? (Male or female)

Which scripture tells about this process and what are the details of it?

Comment: barring rough physical exercise which can lead the hymen to tear, or exceptions where hymen itself doesn't form, blood coming from first intercourse when hymen breaks is the usual test for virginity.